# How to synch controller creation and emitting events?

Tags: angularjs

I am interested if any of you run into this issue and how you solved it. I have a page that has it's controller and in that page, each tab has it's own controller. Depending on how I access the page, via navigation or direct url link, I have issue that tab controllers are not yet ready, by the time outer controller raises event. My solution was to raise "ControllerCreated" event, passing instance of the controller as the event arg. from each of the tab controllers. Outer controller listens for these and invokes on them "load" operation.  Is there other built in way to synch this without having to raise custom event?

Comment: why you dont access the parent controller using $parent??

Comment: You can use something like `ui-router`'s `resolve`: to block loading until all is ready... IMHO, starting to emit and catch events is a code stink...

Comment: @entre: Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: @malix: I agree that it is not good solution, that is why I asked the question. I don't use ui-router, but a built in angular router. I'll take a look at 'resolve' and see if I can figure out what you mean.

Comment: If you had a Plunker / CodePen/ jsFiddle, I could "fix" it for you in an answer :)

Comment: My approach is to store outer events in a service and have child controllers use the service to "catch-up" and subscribe to the events.

Comment: @georgeawg: That sounds interesting solution. Would you mind sharing more details, or maybe sharing service code?

Answer (score 0):

### Event Recorder Service

One approach is to store outer events in a service and have child controllers use the service to "catch-up" and subscribe to the events.

```
app.service("eventRecorder", function() {
    var lastEvent;
    var subscriberIdNum = 0;
    var subscriberList = {};

    this.record = function evRecorder (eventValue) {
        lastEvent = eventValue;
    };

    this.subscribe = function evSubscribe(callbackFn) {
        //callback for subscriber to "catch-up"
        if (lastEvent) { callbackFn(lastEvent) };
        //save subscriber
        subscriberIdNum++
        var subscriberIdString = 'id'+subscriberIdNum;
        subscriberList[subscriberIdString] = callbackFn;
        //return unSubscribe function
        return function unSubscribe() {
             delete subscriberList[subscriberIdString];
        };
    };

    this.notify = function evNotify( eventValue ) {
        this.record(eventValue);
        angular.forEach(subscriberList, function (cb) {
            cb(eventValue);
        });
    };
});
```

### Client Controller Example

```
app.controller("client", function($scope, eventRecorder) {
     var vm = $scope;

     var unSubscribe = eventRecorder.subscribe(function(value) {
         //callback executes immediately to "catch-up"
         vm.eventValue = value;
     });

     $scope.$on('$destroy', unSubscribe);
});
```

### Parent Controller Usage

```
app.controller("parent", function($scope, eventRecorder) {
     var vm = $scope;

     vm.onEvent(value) {
         eventRecorder.notify(value);
     });
});
```

In order to prevent memory leaks, controllers should unsubscibe on destruction of the scope.

This example shows an event recorder service that provides only one feed. It can be generalized to handle more that one feed.

---

### UPDATE: Automatic Unsubscribe

> "In order to prevent memory leaks, controllers should unsubscibe on destruction of the scope." I know what you mean, we had similar notification service, but we pulled it out, because somebody would always forget to unsubscribe.

One could require scope as a `subscribe` function argument and implement automatic unsubsciption.

```
    this.subscribe = function evSubscribe(scope, callbackFn) {
        //callback for subscriber to "catch-up"
        if (lastEvent) { callbackFn(lastEvent) };
        //save subscriber
        subscriberIdNum++
        var subscriberIdString = 'id'+subscriberIdNum;
        subscriberList[subscriberIdString] = callbackFn;

        var unSubscribe = function evUnsubscribe() {
            delete subscriberList[subscriberIdString];
        };

        scope.$on("$destroy", unSubscribe);

        return unSubscribe;

    };
```

Comment: "In order to prevent memory leaks, controllers should unsubscibe on destruction of the scope."  I know what you mean, we had simmilar notification service, but we pulled it out, because somebody would always forget to unsubscribe.